# How do you read the entire text file inside a paint" ";?

Tags: php, printing, text-files, fgets

First time I ask a question here and sorry for my english. So, here's my code:

```
function data1_show() {
    $f = fopen("data/data1.txt", "r");
    while (feof($f)!=true) {
        $line = fgets($f);
        print $line."<br>";
    }  
    fclose($f);
    print "<div id=\"s1\" class=\"s\"> </div>";
}
```

Not the best, but it works  at least. But I want to read the text file inside the print "div /div", and this is the problem. I've tried several reading methods and none of them worked. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You mean read text inside div, or you want to put text from file inside taht div?

Answer (score 0):

You can do explode:

```
$array = explode('div', $text_data);
```

and then use $array and proper element of it that you want.

You can also use RegExp:

```
preg_match("/^div([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.\+\-]).*//div$/, $content, $res);
```

The regexp is better I haven't tested that.